# Can't authenticateHandler. Use of unresolved identifier 'CGLocalPlayer'

Tags: swift, swift2

The code is in the viewDidLoad function in the GameViewController.swift. I have imported `GameKit`. Why is `CGLocalPlayer.localPlayer()` an unresolved identifier?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

var localPlayer = CGLocalPlayer.localPlayer() //error: Use of unresolved identifier 'CGLocalPlayer'

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        //handle authentication
        if ((viewController) != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{

            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Swift 2, you should use `GKLocalPlayer` and not `CGLocalPlayer`.

Comment: I got 
cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController!, NSError!) -> Void' to type '((UIViewController?, NSError?) -> Void)?'
I changed the ! to ?. Then in the if statement I changed viewController to viewController!. Now I don't have any errors but I want to make sure that this was the right step.

Comment: Yes - that's fine. I don't have access to my laptop now else I could explain you how.